# Why do the Values appear outside of the mat-expansion-panel?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list of items that are in related groups. I looked into the Angular/Material select component, but my list of values is too long. Ideally, they would show up in collapsible groups within the multi-select control.

I decided to try and combine the *mat-accordion* > *mat-expansion-panel* with a *mat-select multiple*. The overall function of this is exactly what I was trying to achieve, but there is a rendering issue the ***FIRST*** time the control loads.

Upon initially opening the dropdown, all panels are closed and function normally. When the control loses focus the ***FIRST*** time, all panels appear to be automatically expanded. On closer inspection, the panels are "closed" but the multiselect values are rendered outside of the collapsed panels. Once I open the control for a second time and manually open and close the panels, they function properly there-after, with the values residing "inside" of the collapsed panels, regardless of selection or losing focus.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Would it be a CSS thing?

Example here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26so63-dyicsx)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Text" [formControl]="myControl" multiple>
    <mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let group of myGroups">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            {{ group.name }}
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of group.item" [value]="item.value">
          {{ item.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```